# I think I've gone crazy: Google Sheet Lookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, lookup

I'm trying to do a really simple `lookup` on a data validation field:
I have 4 simple values:

- risk free
- low
- intermediate
- high

and besides those I have the values for those:

- 0
- 0.1
- 0.2
- 0.5

I use the `lookup` formula as follows:

```
=LOOKUP(J11,H7:H10,I7:I10)
```

When I then change the values to let's say `low` or `risk free`, it always shows me the value 0.5.
But when I change the words to this:

- abc
- def
- ghi
- jkl

it delivers the right values.
I tried several different sheets, browsers as well as google accounts which uses different languages (english & german).
Can somebody please explain this to me :D

[image]

[image]

Comment: I notice that in the working example the words are in **alphabetic order**  see:  https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drop the lookup and use:

```
=VLOOKUP(J11, H7:I10, 2, 0)
```

Comment: This worked thank you! But why is lookup behaving so weirdly?

Comment: @JosefGrinspun could be the mentioned "sorted" range requirement... but vertical VLOOKUP and horizontal HLOOKUP are kinda more convenient